# Start function over, depending on results of IF statement

Tags: php

If I have a function that is inside of a Class, and I am returned with "invalid" how can I start back up at the top function?

```
function test(){

    //curl here

    //other stuff here

    if(strpos($data, 'invalid')){
        print "invalid";
               //discard and remove
        continue ;
    }

}
```

but I get the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in

If I am hit with **"invalid**" I would like to start `test()` back over..

Comment: You should post your whole code, because it currently seems that you're using a continue statement without being in a loop (like a 'for' or 'while).

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use a recursive function here:

```
function test(){

    //curl here

    //other stuff here

    if(strpos($data, 'invalid')){
        print "invalid";
           //discard and remove
        return test() ; // restart process
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, this may be a (very rare) good use of the [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) operator:

```
function test(){
    start:
    //curl here

    //other stuff here

    if(strpos($data, 'invalid')){
        print "invalid";
           //discard and remove
        goto start;
    }
}
```

Note that this will only work in PHP >=5.3.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have tried this and was given the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function test() in "

Comment: @henry Your function is actually called `test`, yes?

Comment: Yes, the function is called test

Answer (score 3):

I'd make use of [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), and let the calling scope control repeat invocations of `test()`. `test()` performs one job; it shouldn't control *when* it's asked to perform that job.

(Recursive approaches given in other examples don't really fit the use case [and make me nervous, thanks to languages where recursing too many times makes you run out of stack space eventually; certainly you're filling up your stack for no reason], and though `goto` will work fine it still gives the function itself too much power.)

```
function test()
{
    //curl here
    //other stuff here

    if (strpos($data, 'invalid'))
        throw new Exception("Data is invalid");
}

function callingFunction()
{
   while (true) {
      try {
         test();
         break;  // only reached if test() didn't throw
      }
      catch(Exception $e) {} // if we fall into this, the loop repeats
   }
}
```

You could still apply `goto` quite cleanly with this approach:

```
function test()
{
    //curl here
    //other stuff here

    if (strpos($data, 'invalid'))
        throw new Exception("Data is invalid");
}

function callingFunction()
{
startTest:
   try {
      test();
   }
   catch(Exception $e) {
      goto startTest;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `continue;` and instead add `test();`. It's called recursive functions (calling itself).

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I tried that I got Fatal error: Call to undefined function test() in

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do it, the way my teacher normally suggests is to actually call the function again.

```
function test(){

    //curl here

    //other stuff here

    if(strpos($data, 'invalid')){ 
         print "invalid"; 
         //discard and remove continue ; 
         test();
         return;
    }

}
```

My answer might not be the best, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you change the parameters beforehand, you can recursively call the function again with new parameters.  Just make sure there will be an edge case where the function will stop recursing.  As for that, I'd need to see the real code to tell you.

```
function test($data){

//curl here

//other stuff here

if(strpos($data, 'invalid')){
    print "invalid";
           //discard and remove
    test($NEW_DATA);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break out of the function you're currently in, you should use 'return' instead of 'continue'.

Or if you would like to start the processing over, you should put your logic into a loop.